# A polyhedron has $38$ faces (only squares and triangles) and $60$ edges. Find the ratio of square faces to triangle faces.

Tags: polyhedra

> A polyhedron consists of faces only of squares and equilateral triangles. Given that it has $38$ faces and $60$ edges, find the ratio of square faces to triangular faces.

What I tried so far:

I let $x$ be the number of squares and $y$ be the number of triangles. Then we know that $x+y=38$. However, I am having trouble using $x$ and $y$ to relate it to the $60$ since it is harder to visualize.

Can anybody help?

Comment: How many edges do the triangles have?  The squares?  How many times have you counted each edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that each edge of the polyhedron is connected to exactly $2$ faces. Since triangles have $3$ edges and squares have $4$ edges, then $4x+3y=2\times 60$, which together with $x+y=38$ implies that $x=6$ and $y=32$.